# What is a performant way to make Java8 streams produce a formatted string

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, string-formatting, java-stream

Context: given a directory, I'd like to list all the files in there that contain a pattern in their name, ordered by `lastModified` timestamp, and format this list in a Json string where I'd get the name and timestamp of each file:

```
[{"name": "somefile.txt", "timestamp": 123456},
{"name": "otherfile.txt", "timestamp": 456789}]
```

I've got the following code:

```
private StringBuilder jsonFileTimestamp(File file) {
    return new StringBuilder("{\"name\":\"")
            .append(file.getName())
            .append("\", \"timestamp\":")
            .append(file.lastModified())
            .append("}");
}

public String getJsonString(String path, String pattern, int skip, int limit) throws IOException {

    return Files.list(Paths.get(path))
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(file -> {
                return file.getName().contains(pattern);
            })
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> {
                return Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified());
            })
            .skip(skip)
            .limit(limit)
            .map(f -> jsonFileTimestamp(f))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
}
```

This is working well. I am just concerned on the performance of the StringBuilder instantiation (or String concatenation). It is OK as long as the number of files keeps small (which is my case, so I'm fine) but I am curious : what would you suggest as an optimization ? I feel like I should use `reduce` with the correct accumulator and combiner but I can't get my brain around it.

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

I finally went with the following "optimization":

```
private StringBuilder jsonFileTimestampRefactored(StringBuilder res, File file) {
    return res.append(res.length() == 0 ? "" : ",")
            .append("{\"name\":\"")
            .append(file.getName())
            .append("\", \"timestamp\":")
            .append(file.lastModified())
            .append("}");
}

public String getJsonStringRefactored(String path, String pattern, int skip, int limit) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = Files.list(Paths.get(path))
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(file -> file.getName().contains(pattern))
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified()))
            .skip(skip)
            .limit(limit)
            .reduce(new StringBuilder(),
                    (StringBuilder res, File file) -> jsonFileTimestampRefactored(res, file),
                    (StringBuilder a, StringBuilder b) -> a.append(a.length() == 0 || b.length() == 0 ? "" : ",").append(b))
            ;
    return new StringBuilder("[").append(sb). append("]").toString();
}
```

This version is creating only 2 instances of `StringBuilder` when the older one is instantiating as many of them as there are files in the directory.

On my workstation, the first implementation is taking 1289 ms to complete over 3379 files, when the second one takes 1306 ms. The second implementation is costing me 1% more time when I was expecting (very small) savings.

I don't feel like the new version is easier to read or maintain so I'll keep the old one.

Thanks all.

Comment: you probably meant `return name == null ? false`, i.e. exclude null names. Although I'm not sure in what situation this could happen...

Comment: In lambdas, you may remove { return and the closing }

Comment: You can replace `.sorted((f1, f2) -> { return Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified()); })` with `.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified))`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have removed the test on `name` as it is legacy from my production code I forgot to clean for this question.

Comment: You should be using a proper library like Jackson or Gson to create JSON. If a filename has invalid characters in it you'll get invalid JSON. Create a POJO with name and timestamp fields, map to that object, collect to a list, and convert the list to a JSON array with an actual JSON library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String formatting is such a trivial portion of your application's performance that it's almost never worth optimizing; only think about it if profiling shows an actual hot spot. In fact, most applications use reflective JSON mappers, and their bottlenecks are elsewhere (usually I/O). The `StringBuilder` approach you're using is the most efficient way you can do this in Java without manually twiddling character arrays, and it's even going farther than I would myself (I'd use `String#format()`).

Write your code for clarity instead. The current version is fine.

Comment: +1, the only thing which could be improved is to use the `StringBuilder(int)` constructor specifying a higher initial capacity as the resulting length is predictably higher that the default capacity of 16 characters. But right, the I/O will outweigh it all.

Comment: You must be right. Anyway, just out of (scientific) curiosity, and because this could apply to other domains where IO is not the bottleneck, I'm going to try implementing it another way around and I'll let you know =)